# Click button inside listview then trigger gridview to load its button list on android studio

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I have a listview, from database (category list) and i want to load gridview (product gridview) when i click any button in the category listview, i'm able to make the listview and gridview, but cannot connect them, since im still new at android programming and have no clue to do it.

my main purpose is:

1. List category
2. on click on the category button will load gridview of product button
3. on click product button will add the product id to table cart

ps: if you notice i do SQL query in the mainActivity class, i still new at the code so i tried my best first before convert into better practice.

Any suggestion to do it?

Here i include my snippet:
Category.java (setter and getter)

```
public class Category {
    private int _id;
    private String _name;

    public Category() {

    }

    public Category(int id, String name) {
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
    }

    public Category(String name) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return this._id;
    }
    public void setID(int id) {
        this._id = id;
    }

    public String get_name()
    {
        return this._name;
    }
    public void set_name(String name)
    {
        this._name = name;
    }


}
```

CategoryListAdapter.java

```
public class CategoryListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Category> listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CategoryListAdapter(Context aContext, ArrayList<Category> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(aContext);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CategoryListAdapter.ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_category, null);
            holder = new CategoryListAdapter.ViewHolder();
            holder.btnCategory = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnCategory);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (CategoryListAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.btnCategory.setText(listData.get(position).get_name());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        Button btnCategory;
    }
}
```

listview_category.xml (layout that will be repeated)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnCategory"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:background="@drawable/button_category"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

listview inside MainActivity

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listviewCategory"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>
```

java inside MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
/* LIST CATEGORY TO LOAD PRODUCT */
        ArrayList list_category = getListCategory();
        final ListView listview_category = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewCategory);
        listview_category.setAdapter(new CategoryListAdapter(this, list_category));
listview_category.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                                    long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "click cat");
                //Give product list an id from category_id get from here
            }
        });
...
}

/* List Category for selecting category product */
    private ArrayList getListCategory() {
        SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("posDb",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        Cursor resultSet = mydatabase.rawQuery("Select * from categories",null);

        ArrayList<Category> results = new ArrayList<Category>();
        if (resultSet.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Category categoriesData = new Category();
                categoriesData.set_name(resultSet.getString(1));
                results.add(categoriesData);
            } while (resultSet.moveToNext());
        }
        return results;
    }
```

The grid of product mostly the same as category, but load product from database which later i want to onclick the product button to save record to cart table

Answer (score 1):

on Click on button will add the product id in to table_cart

1. MainActivity.java

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      // ArrayList list_category = getListCategory();

       int id[]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
       String categoryName[]={"category1","category2","category3","category4","category5"};
       ArrayList<Category> listData=new ArrayList<>();
       Category category;
       for (int i=0; i<id.length; i++)
       {
           category=new Category();
           category.set_id(id[i]);// setting Id
           category.set_name(categoryName[i]);// setting category name
           listData.add(category);
       }
       final ListView listview_category = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewCategory);
       listview_category.setAdapter(new CategoryListAdapter(this, listData ));

   }
   ```

   }
2. CategoryListAdapter.java

   public class CategoryListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
       private ArrayList listData;
       private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
       ArrayList table_cart = new ArrayList();
       private static final String TAG = "CategoryListAdapter";

   ```
   public CategoryListAdapter(Context aContext, ArrayList<Category> listData) {
       this.listData = listData;
       layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(aContext);
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return listData.size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
       return listData.get(position);
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return position;
   }

   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       final CategoryListAdapter.ViewHolder holder;
       if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_category, null);
           holder = new CategoryListAdapter.ViewHolder();
           holder.btnCategory = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnCategory);


           convertView.setTag(holder);
       } else {
           holder = (CategoryListAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }

       holder.btnCategory.setText(listData.get(position).get_name());

       holder.btnCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

               // getting product id
               int product_id = listData.get(position).getID();
               Log.e(TAG, "product_id: " + product_id);

               // now you can get category name as well
               String category_name = listData.get(position).get_name();
               Log.e(TAG, "category_name: " + category_name);

               // now adding product id in to table_cart
               table_cart.add(listData.get(position).getID());
           }
       });

       return convertView;
   }

   static class ViewHolder {
       Button btnCategory;
   }
   ```

   }
3. Category.java

   public class Category {
       private int _id;
       private String _name;

   ```
   public int getID() {
       return this._id;
   }

   public void setID(int id) {
       this._id = id;
   }

   public String get_name() {
       return this._name;
   }

   public void set_name(String name) {
       this._name = name;
   }

   public void set_id(int _id) {
       this._id = _id;
   }
   ```

   }
4. there is no need to change layouts

Comment: the category name is the button Text, so no need textview, sorry, i dunt understand the point no 3.

Comment: In your purpose 3: You wanted to add product id in table_cart. So I wanted to say that you can can achive this by adding listener on button in CategoryListAdapter.java  and I have edited my MainActivity n adapter class . You can see it and sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0):

Add on click listener for category button, add grid view in fragment and open fragment on button click.

```
 holder.btnCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ProductFragment nextFrag= new ProductFragment();
 this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
 .replace(R.id.Layout_container, nextFrag,TAG_FRAGMENT)
 .commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: where to put the onclicklistener? i dunt use fragment, can we still do without fragment? can we reload the gridview in the same layout? or if not use fragment, must reload the whole layout?

Comment: onclick listener inside getView.Or add an on list item click listener for list view,then show gridview on listview click and hide listview.  Or you can use another activity instead of fragment.

Comment: i update my code above, adding setOnItemClickListener, but nothing happened when i debug it, what was wrong?